# is it possible to compare string to a variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is this piece of code legal?

```
def ask_to_leave():
  if answer == 'y':
    return False
  elif answer == 'n':
    return True
```

I am getting this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "MACROCALC.py", line 62, in <module>
        main()
      File "MACROCALC.py", line 17, in main
        answer = input("Are you done using the calculator?(y/n)")
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

Here is a link to my code

http://pastebin.com/EzqBi0KG

Comment: You don't get `NameError`s with strings...

Comment: This python code is valid - You don't get `NameError` when using strings. You have your problem somewhere other than this code.

Comment: Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: Are you using Python 2?

Comment: I feel like I'm being mocked.

Comment: See Martijn's answer, but in addition (i) your if statement is undefined if answer is something other than 'y' or 'n', and (ii) the if statement can be written as ``return answer == 'n'``.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using the [`input()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) on Python 2, which interprets the input as Python code. Use the [`raw_input()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead.

```
answer = raw_input("Are you done using the calculator?(y/n)")
```

When using `input()`, the entered text is sent to [`eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) which expects a valid python expression, and `y` is seen as a variable name:

```
>>> input('Enter a python expression: ')
Enter a python expression: 1 + 1
2
>>> input('Enter a python expression: ')
Enter a python expression: y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
>>> input('Enter a python expression: ')
Enter a python expression: 'y'
'y'
```

Note how I had to enter `'y'` *with the quotes* for it to work; a literal Python string expression. `raw_input()` has no such restrictions:

```
>>> raw_input('Enter the second-last letter of the alphabet: ')
Enter the second-last letter of the alphabet: y
'y'
```

Comment: Your last point is totally misleading for a new user. It's better to use `2+2`, not `'y'` as an example.

Comment: @kirelagin: Why is that misleading? I am showing how useless `input()` is for handling 'yes / no' questions..

Comment: @kirelagin: That's the first example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah, but instead you've shown how to actually use it to input strings. That's not only a bit difficult to understand for a new user, but also kinda dangerous since they might start using it to do actual input (since it works nice for raw strings, as we can see, you just quote them).

Comment: @kirelagin: He does point out first, that he should be using raw_input(). This is hardly misleading.

Comment: OK, but I still believe this is dangerous since using `input` this way introduces a major security problem. I know, people are not that stupid and all that stuff, but the truth is that software quality and security is already too bad. It's like saying “you should be using AES in CTR mode, but here is an example in ECB mode, just never use it because it's totally insecure.”

Comment: @kirelagin: The security risks of `eval()` are a valid but *different* point. :-)

Comment: Just yesterday I was answering a question here on SO about bytes and encodings, and the OP was using plain RSA to “encrypt” his data. I fell that it's _my responsibility_ to warn him that he never should do this even if the question was nowhere near encryption. And this includes “never do this” written in bold and does not include an example of how he should never even try to do.

Comment: @kirelagin: sure, when writing answers here on SO, taking into account the wider picture is always helpful.